# Expected tries without replacement

Tags: probability, computer-science, conditional-expectation

I am calculating the number of blackbox fuzzing test I need to run on a program to find an error.

Say there is a 1/100 chance that my program throws an error. It takes in two arguments. What is the expected number of tests I need to run if no pair of arguments will ever be repeated?

Example:

```
x=1, y=1 -> PASS
x=2, y=1 -> PASS
x=1, y=1 -> ALREADY CALLED - SKIP
x=5, y=6 -> CRASH
etc.
```

Comment: since the prob of error is 1/100, means that every 100 tries an error should appear (on average)

Comment: To what level of confidence do you want your Type 1 and Type 2 errors?